# Is there a ruby idiom for returning the first array element, if only one exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I would like to return the first element of an array, if the array only contains one value.

Currently, I use:

```
vals.one? ? vals.first : vals.presence
```

Thus:

```
vals = []; vals.one? ? vals.first : vals.presence
# => nil

vals = [2]; vals.one? ? vals.first : vals.presence
# => 2

vals = [2, 'Z']; vals.one? ? vals.first : vals.presence
# => [2, "Z"]
```

Is there something inbuilt that does this, or does it with a better design consideration?

---

My use case is specific, involving presenters that know what to expect from the method (which would implement the above code). If those presenters handle all returns as an array, then in most cases (~90%) they will iterate over arrays of size `1` or `0`.

Comment: *My* idiom is: don't change the data shape. This violates that rule as `vals` can either be a single (non-collection) value or a sequence (collection) of values - they are differently shaped results. As far as code, I've not seen "more idiomatic" for the desired task.

Comment: Why not just `vals.first unless vals.first.nil?`

Comment: Note that `[false].one?` and `[nil].one?` both return false.

Comment: As some others have hinted, this is a very bad idea - I speak from experience.  If you implement this, then *every* call site needs to check the return type, and then act differently when it receives a scalar vs. an array. Just let the method "naturally" return a 1-element array, if it wants, and allow the call sites to know that they will *always* receive an array.

Comment: @user2864740 and Bob, I get what you're saying, which is probably why there is no idiom.  My use case is specific, involving presenters that know what to expect from the method (which would implement the above code).  I suppose you'd suggest that those presenters handle all returns as an array, and in most cases iterate over arrays of size `1` or `0`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what they should do, expect an array and process all the elements in the array. If there's only one they'll only need to do it once.

Comment: wrapping everything in an `each`, `collect` or other Iterator just feels wonky

Comment: Worth pointing out that this is exactly what the .pluck method does in rails 4, bad idea or not...

Comment: @KeiranBetteley `pluck` [is not an Array method.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21901202/263858)

Comment: Sure, but pluck pulls back an array of hashes and returns values. If only one column is requested, an array of single objects comes back. If you request more than one column, an array of arrays comes back. So the functionality is exactly the 'bad idea' we're being warned against here (for better or worse).

Comment: @KeiranBetteley I appreciate the thinking, but this is a little different, I think.  In the `pluck` example is quite similar, but never does it return `nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to handle the case of val array being undefined so...

```
val.size > 1 ? val : val[0] if defined?(val)
```

But as has been pointed out it would be better to deliver a consistent argument (always arrays) so the following will deliver the val array or an empty array if undefined

```
defined?(val) ? val : []
```