# how to pluck email from array of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I do `User.all.pluck(:email)` then it works fine.

But if I do

```
arr = Array.new
arr = User.all
```

and then

```
arr.pluck(:email)
```

this is raising following error

```
undefined method `pluck' for #<Array:0x007f4ff8daf3c8>
```

which means I cannot use pluck with arrays, so how can we get particular field value from an array of records in just one line like above.
**I don't want to loop through each record in an array**.

Comment: `User.all.pluck(:email)` works fine? what rails version are you using?

Comment: m using Rails4 and ruby2.0.0

Comment: everyones answer is working....so m going to vote up  all but accept @apneadiving 's answer

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`pluck` is useful to do a minimalist db query.

When you have an array, just use `map`:

```
arr.map(&:email)
```

Comment: But on a really big array, you might be better off with a new DB query using `pluck` ...

Comment: @Jon no. Once you've data in memory, everything is faster than another db call

Comment: Perhaps. But replacing `arr = User.all ; arr.map` with `User.pluck` is far more optimal. His question is ambiguous with regards to whether altering the initial selection from the DB is possible. I just think the performance improvement of getting the DB to provide what you need rather than manipulating the data after fetching it is worth considering.

Comment: Yes, its the first part of my answer

Comment: When I was a rails novice I would not have understood the complexities of the issue based on the first line of your answer.

Comment: Excellent answer...just the thing i was looking for... I have realized that if one can master map, one can create really cool programs .... any suggestion in this domain ?

Comment: Pluck has the ability to return more than one column whereas a map is limited to a single column.

Comment: yes it changed since I initially answered

Answer (score 15):

Use [`collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html), it's an Array method:

```
arr.collect{|u| u.email}
```

Answer (score 8):

`pluck(:x)` is the equivalent of `select(:x).map(&:x)` on an `ActiveRecord` collection.

If you have an array, `Array#map` and its alias `Array#collect` do the same job.

If you use

`User.scoped.pluck(:email)`

your query will be like

`SELECT users.email FROM users`

So, to answer the question, you can NOT use pluck on an array, [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) is an `ActiveRecord::Calculations` method, not an array one.

Comment: It's not really equivalent at all. `pluck` causes a modification to the `SELECT` portion of the DB query. The `map` method iterates over an `Array`. Whilst the products might be the same, the processes to provide them are absolutely NOT equivalent.

Comment: @Jon I say that the compination of Activerecord's `select` chained by `map` is equivalent, not `map` alone.

Comment: I think that it's appropriate to say that `pluck` is the equivalent of `select` and `map` *together*, as @xlembouras does.  He wasn't saying it was equivalent to either of them on their own.

Comment: I just thing that for clarity to developers unfamiliar with the differences between them, it's misleading to say that they are equivalent. The mechanisms behind each option are substantially different and have real performance implications depending on your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to array this way is a memory hogger. Instead you can use:

```
arr = User.scoped
arr.pluck :email
```

or in a more easy to read:

```
User.scoped.pluck :email
```

This will make sure that actual user objects are not loaded into memory until they are required.