# Convert array to single object if array is a single object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Really simple question.

Is there a method to do the following?

```
["a"] => "a"
[1] => 1
[1,"a"] => [1, "a"]
```

i.e. if an array is a single object, return the object, otherwise return the array. 
Without doing something ugly like

```
array.length == 1 ? array[0] : array
```

Comment: Not to my knowledge -- but why would you want to do this? Whatever you're passing this data to should respond to either an array or a string, popping out a single value if it's alone means that your code further along has to know how to deal with both arrays and strings, rather than just relying n always having an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a ruby idiom for returning the first array element, if only one exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109800/is-there-a-ruby-idiom-for-returning-the-first-array-element-if-only-one-exists)

Comment: Doing this has code smell.

Comment: To clarfiy, one of the reasons I want to do it is that I want to replicate the functionality of the .pluck method in rails 4 for rails 3.
Pluck in rails 4 returns either single objects, if only one column is plucked, or an array of multiple objects, if multiple objects are plucked.

Comment: In terms of the duplicate. You probably have a point there. However, I'm not sure that the question title is easy enough to find in order to stop people being stuck. (Hence I didn't find it...) Not sure if I accept the duplicate in that case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you should stick to what you wrote - it's simple and does what it should.

of course you may always monkey patch the Array definition... (unrecommended, but it does what you expect)

```
class Array
  def first_or_array
    length > 1 ? self : self[0]
  end
end

[1].first_or_array # 1
[1, 2].first_or_array # [1, 2]
```

Comment: Exactly this! I was going to post the same. But I'd add something. This not excludes the possibility of having something like [[1,2]] and then [[1,2]].first_of_array  = [1,2], still an array, although the content is a single object (another array). This would have to be something recursive, if the goal is to reach a single object.

Comment: If you can't do any better than the OP, you should just suggest the OP to go with that way. This does need to be an answer. It could just be a comment.